# Instalar Plugins con Gulp

Tags: gulp

tengo una duda;

--save-dev instala los plugin de manera local en mi proyecto.

Pero muchos de los plugins que uso como jade y sass con gulp siempre tengo que estar instalándolos en cada proyecto; ¿como puedo hacer para instalar a nivel global y utilizarlos de esa manera y ya no estar instalando en cada proyecto dichos plugins y así evitar hacer mas pesado cada carpeta de mis proyectos?

Comment: No debes instalarlos a nivel global ya que muchos módulos tienen una función diferente cuando son instalados a nivel global o local. Para lo que quieres te puede servir copiar la carpeta que está en `node_modules` siempre y cuando las versiones sean idénticas.

Answer (score 1):

La funcicón de `--save-dev` no es instalar de manera local en tu proyecto.

Existen dos tipos de paquetes.

1) Los que son **requeridos** para que tu proyecto funcione.
`--save`

2) Los que son **requeridos** para el **desarrollo** de tu proyecto.
`--save-dev`

Si otro desarrollador quiere **sólo** utilizar tu módulo (proyecto), no le interesa instalar las dependencias de desarrollo.

En cambio, si quiere modificar tu proyecto, debe instalar las dependencias de desarrollo.

Es por eso que un `sass` no se instala con `--save` para que en `package.json` se agregue en `dependencies`, sino que se debe instalar como dependecia de desarrolo con `--saveDev` y se agregará en `devDependencies`

En mi opinión, copiar y pegar `node_modules` es una muy mala práctica, por el tema de las versiones de los paquetes.